# How to get reference to first nested table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

How to get reference to the second table nested within first one (second table has no id nor class) :

```
    <table class='top'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("table.top table")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find DOM elements with functions [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) which return array (or better array-like object) of elements:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0]; // or other selector
var nestedTable = table.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

with plain javascript you can use 
`document.querySelector('table table')` which searches for the first table element in the document, takes the found table element and searches inside it for the next table element.

if you can use jQuery just call `$('table table')` or `$('table').next('table')` its like using querySelector but returns an jQuery Object

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0].getElementsByTagName('table')[0]`